# 'column "survey_data.start_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function' when using agg_json

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to run the following PostgreSQL query:

```
sql = """SELECT json_agg(survey_data)
            FROM survey_data.survey_data 
            WHERE codigo_do_projeto LIKE '%%%s%%'
            ORDER BY data_de_inicio_da_coleta desc 
            LIMIT %s
            OFFSET %s*%s""" % (survey_name,items_per_page, items_per_page,page_number)
```

However it throws this error:

> 'column "survey_data.data_de_inicio_da_coleta" must appear in the
> GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function\nLINE 4:
> ORDER BY data_de_inicio_da_coleta desc \n
> ^\n'

I really want it the query result to come out as a dict because it is being a lot of trouble to convert it to one (and it looks sloopy).

Comment: You are aggregating everything into a single column and row. The `order by` (and the limit and offset) is completely unnecessary, so just remove it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. The `order by` works to order the objects/elements inside the array produced by `json_agg`. So it not completely unnecessary.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: really? That's applied _after_ the aggregation

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, try it and see.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Well, the query won't work with the ORDER BY without adding a GROUP BY on that column. However, once the GROUP BY is included, the ORDER BY won't make a difference for the elements in the JSON array as all of them have the same value for the `data_de_inicio_da_coleta`. But without a GROUP BY, the query returns a single row and a single column. The ORDER BY wouldn't make a difference if it was legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says `data_de_inicio_da_coleta desc` needs to be used in a `GROUP BY` or used in the aggregate function.

So your choices are, throw a GROUP BY in the query:

```
SELECT json_agg(survey_data)
FROM survey_data.survey_data 
WHERE codigo_do_projeto LIKE '%%%s%%'
GROUP BY data_de_inicio_da_coleta desc
ORDER BY data_de_inicio_da_coleta desc 
LIMIT %s
OFFSET %s*%s
```

Or use in the aggregate function:

```
SELECT json_agg(survey_data ORDER BY data_de_inicio_da_coleta desc)
FROM survey_data.survey_data 
WHERE codigo_do_projeto LIKE '%%%s%%'
LIMIT %s
OFFSET %s*%s
```

As to the convert to `dict` part. Using `RealDictCursor` from [psycopg2.extras](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html):

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres', port=5432, cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("select * from animals order by animal")

cur.fetchall()

[RealDictRow([('pk_animals', 200), ('cond', 'good'), ('animal', 'crow')]),
 RealDictRow([('pk_animals', 45), ('cond', 'poor'), ('animal', "'dog'")]),
 RealDictRow([('pk_animals', 2), ('cond', 'good'), ('animal', 'eagle')]),
 RealDictRow([('pk_animals', 35), ('cond', 'good'), ('animal', 'emu')]),
 RealDictRow([('pk_animals', 101), ('cond', 'good'), ('animal', 'gopher')]),
 RealDictRow([('pk_animals', 16), ('cond', 'fair'), ('animal', 'heron')]),
 RealDictRow([('pk_animals', 33), ('cond', 'fair'), ('animal', 'mole')]),
 RealDictRow([('pk_animals', 3), ('cond', 'good'), ('animal', 'mole')])]
```

Comment: What a wonderful answer! Thank you!